# Getting information about the standard browser with Java

Tags: java, browser

My Java app opens html documents by letting the windows default file handler deal with them. Before doing this I'd like to determine (for statistics) what the standard browser is and which version is installed.

Is it possible to find this information anywhere?

**Update** This app runs only on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in a standard or portable way. You'd need access to some facilities of the OS.

**EDIT:** On Windows, I think your only option is to mine the registry, possibly using a WSH script that you invoke using the `Process` class. Nasty.

Comment: apparently you can query the registry via some pure-java trickery ... http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/reading-windows-registry-java-without-jni

Comment: @amir75: Holy smokes!!! He sums it up himself: "Of course, this approach is pure evil".

Comment: Anything involving the Registry is already heading for the Evil side of things in the first place, and discovering what the browser is and how to invoke it is fairly messy even once you've got access to the Registry. Some things, I'm glad to have forgotten…